# MySQL - Return associative array by query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I need to know if there is a chance to get an PHP5 array from a MySQL PDO Query like this:

```
Array = (
    keywordID = 1321,
    keyword = "Its a test",
    position = Array(
        today = 12,
        month = 17
    )
)
```

Now i have this MySQL Query:

```
    $sql = "SELECT
                keywords.id AS keywordID,
                keywords.keyword,
                statistic.position
            FROM
                keywords
            LEFT JOIN statistic ON (statistic.kid = keywords.id)
            WHERE
                keywords.uid = ? AND statistic.date IN (?, ?)";
    $stmt = WPStatsDB::getInstance()->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute(array($array['userID'], date("d.m.Y", time()), date("d.m.Y", strtotime('-30 days'))));
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

This is the current result of var_dump($result):

This is one of the results. I try to write it in my post.

```
array(244) {
...

[1]=>
  array(6) {
    ["keywordID"]=>
    string(4) "1978"
    [0]=>
    string(4) "1978"
    ["keyword"]=>
    string(20) "Weiterbildung in NRW"
    [1]=>
    string(20) "Weiterbildung in NRW"
    ["position"]=>
    string(2) "38"
    [2]=>
    string(2) "38"
  }
...
}
```

## EDIT 1:

I need the attribute position as array with two values not as int with only one value. I need position as array with the two attributes for less database queries.
Today and Month are values with information of position of today and the position from the day a month ago of today.

## EDIT 2:

Sorry, i've forgot to say that i can't edit this table. The table statistics contains the stats of every day of every keyword connected to every domain. It's very big.

I really don't know how i can solve this.

Thanks for help!! :-)

Comment: WHAT IS THE RESULT OF `$result`?

Comment: This is one of the results. I try to write it in my post.
[1]=>
  array(6) {
    ["keywordID"]=>
    string(4) "1978"
    [0]=>
    string(4) "1978"
    ["keyword"]=>
    string(20) "Weiterbildung in NRW"
    [1]=>
    string(20) "Weiterbildung in NRW"
    ["position"]=>
    string(2) "38"
    [2]=>
    string(2) "38"
  }

Comment: so what's the problem? you are getting values?

Comment: Why you want to cast numeric (statistic.position) to Array? And how to know which name to use ? (today, month...etc)

Comment: where the information about "today" and "month" supposed to come from?

Comment: I need the attribute position as array with two values not as int with only one value. I need position as array with the two attributes for less database queries.
Today and Month are values with information of position of today and the position from the day a month ago of today.

Comment: Be aware that this is an INNER JOIN.

Comment: Why don't you have position_today and position_month in statistic table? How do you know to split your position if the value is "113" for example?

Comment: Sorry, i've forgot to say that i can't edit this table. The table statistics contains the stats of every day of every keyword connected to every domain. It's very big.

Comment: How do you know to split your position if the value is "113" for example? It's November 3 or January 13 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's arguable what's faster, in a lot of cases is faster to do separated queries for the relationship.

You either

1) Get a row for each position and deal with it after you get the result

2) Go on a loop for each keyword and get the positions on a separate query for each keyword

3) You do a group by keyword id in MySQL and retrieve the positions with something like group_concat. You can then parse that afterwards. This may seem faster but probably depends on your dataset and may not be as good as you'd expect it to be.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Use any [ORM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping), [list of examples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_object-relational_mapping_software#PHP)